# Tap MKAnnotationView with XCTestCase

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, uitest

I want to tap `MKAnnotationView` using my `XCTestCase` with UITest, so I have my mapView as a `XCUIElement`. I have no idea how to get annotations from mapView, I don't want to put fixed positions on this on the screens because it is tested on various devices. So I'm stuck on the
`let mapView:XCUIElement = app.maps.elementBoundByIndex(0)`

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to add an accessibility identifier ?

Answer (score 2):

To interact with a map annotation use `otherElements` referenced by the `title` attribute.

For example, in your production code set a title in your `MKAnnotation`.

```
class Annotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let title: String?

    init(title: String?, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}

let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.703490, -73.987770)
let annotation = Annotation(title: "BeerMenus HQ", coordinate: coordinate)
let mapView = MKMapView()
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Then under test you can reference the annotation via it's `title` attribute.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let annotation = app.maps.element.otherElements["BeerMenus HQ"]
annotation.tap()
```

Comment: This can also be done with an AccessibilityIdentifier, I think, which would be a more "correct" way of doing it per what Apple wants us to use.

Comment: It *could* be down with an accessibility identifier. But if you are already setting the `title` why not just use that? The `MKAnnotation` protocol requires `title`.

Comment: Title's user-facing, right? Separating the user-facing stuff from the test infrastructure means that you can change one without changing the other. Whether that matters at all depends entirely on the team, I expect!

Comment: In my case, I could not access the pin annotation using `app.maps.element.otherElements["title"]` since my annotation does not have a title. However I was able to access it by `app.otherElements["accessibilityIdentifier"]`. Please note that this did only work when `maps`was omitted.